# How do I change collection color?

Tags: customization, collections

[image: Preference settings]

**I noticed in the preference settings that there is an option to change the colors of different collections, but how do I actually change a collection with color 1 for example? This would really help to organize bigger projects.**

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the collection:

[image]

Comment: damn....30 secs quicker than i was :(

Comment: well, you don't have the cape

Comment: daaaaaaaaaaamnnn you are right 